# Selecting next option with MUI Select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having a dropdown select from MUI in a Nextjs app and i want to add two arrows that move to the next/previous option.

This is my code now:

```
 <StyledFormControl>
      <Select
        value={currentUrl}
        defaultValue=''
        id='server-select'
        MenuProps={{ keepMounted: true, disablePortal: true }}
        sx={{ zIndex: 99 }}
      >
        {countriesData?.map((country: any) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem value={country?.attributes.Slug} key={country.id}>
              <Link href={country?.attributes?.Slug}>
                {country?.attributes.Country} - {country?.attributes.City}
              </Link>
            </MenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </Select>
      <Button onClick={DO_SOMETHING}>NEXT</Button>
      <FormHelperText>Select another VPS Server Location</FormHelperText>
    </StyledFormControl>
```

Any help how can i achieve this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not attempting to advance the [`Select`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) directly, but advance the underlying `value` prop driving the controlled `Select` using the `index`es of your array list.

In this example, I'm keeping track of the `index` of the currently selected item, and then driving the `Select` and [`Button`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/) functionality from it.  *(This could be done much better, but this is a quick and dirty example for illustration.)*

```
  // Helper to get the index of the currently selected item
  const getSelectedIndexById = (selectedId) => {
    return countries.findIndex(({ id }) => selectedId === id);
  };

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState("1");

  // To keep track of the list by index
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
    setSelectedIndex(getSelectedIndexById(event.target.value));
  };

  // Handler to set the currently selected index to the item
  // before it in the array
  const handlePrevious = React.useCallback(() => {
    setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex - 1);
  }, [selectedIndex]);

  // Handler to set the currently selected index to the item
  // after it in the array
  const handleNext = React.useCallback(() => {
    setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex + 1);
  }, [selectedIndex]);

  // Effect to set the currently selected option based off of the
  // newly selected index.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedValue(countries[selectedIndex].id); // You'll probably want to handle the empty/nothing selected case
  }, [selectedIndex]);

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={0}>
      <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, width: 200 }}>
        <Select
          id="demo-simple-select-standard"
          value={selectedValue}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Country"
        >
          {countries.map(({ id, name }) => (
            <MenuItem value={id}>{name}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <ButtonWrapper>
        <IconButton onClick={handlePrevious} disabled={selectedIndex === 0}>
          <NavigateBackIcon fontSize="small" />
        </IconButton>
      </ButtonWrapper>
      <ButtonWrapper>
        <IconButton
          onClick={handleNext}
          disabled={selectedIndex === countries.length - 1}
        >
          <NavigateNextIcon fontSize="small" />
        </IconButton>
      </ButtonWrapper>
    </Stack>
  );
```

Which produces:
[image: example screenshot]

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/advance-select-via-buttons-2t6h8v?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: Great! this was leading me to the right direction. Thanks!